# API GET Authentication

Tags: api, powershell, authentication

I will start by saying I'm not a developer and don't know too much about API's.

Using BambooHR (Cloud based HR service) I have an API that I can call through a browser and it returns a CSV report. I am looking to automate this but not too sure how to call this through PowerShell to return my file.

The API url looks like this:

```
HTTP://<API TOKEN >:x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/<COMPANY Name>/reports/<report>/?format=csv
```

When I try the following in Powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI HTTP://<API TOKEN>:x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/<COMPANY Name>/reports/<report>/?format=csv
```

I get the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.

Any ideas how I can just create a simple PowerShell script to download this file?

Answer (score 0):

According to bamboohr api documentation you should only use https with signed certificate:

> All requests made to our APIs must be sent over HTTPS. The SSL
>   certificate used for the HTTPS connection is signed and all
>   implementations should configure their SSL layer to verify it.

Comment: How would I incorporate that in my Powershell script/command?